How to use Caitlyn in Roblox Bedwars? I have listed a number of disadvantages. How to use it despite the disadvantages?
In my opinion Caitlyn kit is pretty hard to play with. Especially in squads and duos. The contracts aren't that epic either way.
In Squads and duos, it is very impractical to go to another team's base and kill the person you require to kill. Even if they come to centre, it's pretty tough to target a specific person. You are a disadvantage already by ignoring other players. Even if you manage to kill or get a share of the kill which fulfils your contract, you are dying at most cases, which means you lose your sword and walk over to the centre once again.
In duos it's easier still, but the fact that you can't challenge a person in early game cuz their mate is to rescue to them, takes away the advantage Caitlyn should have. Afterall if Caitlyn isn't powerful by the time your enemies get powerful, how is it in an advantage anyway. Plus, you will have to sacrifice your going to centre and collecting loot, although I know this is a necessary opportunity cost to consider.
Now the case regarding solo is the game finishes so early on, that you do not have time to get a good lot of contracts done.
Can anyone who's experienced with Caitlyn, or kits like her refer me some tactics that I may use in order to play effectively with Caitlyn.
